# Read jquery value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am calling rest api through jquery and i need to read the videoList value in javascript.

below my code,every time alert is saying undifined.

How to read videoList in javascript?

Comment: This is my code 

$(document).ready(function() {

    $.get('https://123/movies', function(data) {

        $("#videoList").data(data.entries);

    });
});

var list = $("#videoList").listview;
alert(list);

Comment: You should move the alert inside the success callback since alert will run before data is retrieved.

Comment: Put your code in the question, not a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I added your code into the ticket, and there are two issues to look at.

Here is your original code:

```
    $(document).ready(
        function() { 
            $.get(
                '123/movies';, 
                function(data) { 
                    $("#videoList").data(data.entries);
                }
            ); 
        }
    ); 
    var list =  $("#videoList").listview; 
    alert(list);
```

You have an extra semicolon in your parameters to "get()" (after '123/movies').

We can't see your HTML, which could provide a clue.

Also, because it is outside of "$(document).ready(...)", your code to fetch videoList and alert the result is running before the page finishes loading.

Comment: Why would this work? The alert is going to run before the Ajax call finishes.

Comment: That's exactly what I was saying.  I pasted the original code because my edit had not been approved.

Comment: The alert needs to be inside the success callback, not just inside the ready function.